# Required Permanent URLs of images from S3 without showing the path of image in S3 bucket

Tags: java

I am new to AWS S3 Service. Now I want to store all the images in S3, I am using S3 presigned URL to PUT Image. Now I want to show the Image to the users. I found 2 ways to do this:

Give the public access to S3 Bucket (Which I don't want to do that).
Presigned URLs for GET object. (but user can view the directory structure)

I want something like permanent URLs to view image and but without showing the path of the image as it is in S3 Bucket. For example, currently the URL has the structure like this :

domain.com///?

but I want something like this:

domain.com/ some code is like a pointer to get the image from s3 bucket's directory. Please give me a hint to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932737/s3-pre-signed-url-without-path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177325/how-to-generate-an-s3-pre-signed-url-for-a-custom-domain-without-exposing-bucket